# How can I get my image replacing javascript code to work in an external .js file

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm new to web development (career change) and I'm hitting a roadblock that I can't seem to get past.

I'm trying to write a script that will change the img src in my HTML. When I use inline JavaScript it does what I want and replaces the image:

```html
<img id="book1" src="placeholder" alt="Book1">
<h5 class="title">TITLE by Author Name</h5>
<p>Book description</p>
<div class="center">
  <button type="button" class="amz-btn" id="btn1" onclick="showImage()">Buy from Amazon</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showImage() {
      let image = document.getElementById("book1");
      if (image.src.match("placeholder")) {
        image.src = "https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781538728529.jpg";
      } else {
        console.log("This is frustrating");
      }
    }
  </script>
```

But when I transfer it to my external .js file I get a syntax error saying `showImage` is not defined.
How can I resolve this?

Here is the code as written just in the external file

```
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", showImage)
function showImage() {
  let image = document.getElementById("book1");
  if (image.src.match("placeholder")) {
    image.src = "https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781538728529.jpg";
  }
  else {
    console.log("This is frustrating");
  }
}
```

Someone suggested that I use addEventListener rather than onclick in the HTML so I've done that but I'm confident it's in entirely the wrong place and doing the wrong thing

I've tried running the following in the browser console and it runs perfectly but I still can't get it to work from the external file

```
      const img = "https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781538728529.jpg";

      document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", showImage);

      function showImage() {
        document.getElementById("book1").src = img;
      }
```

Comment: Can you show us the external JavaScript version.

Comment: Also, in your JavaScript it would be better to not use the onclick attribute in the HTML but add the event listener using JavaScript - `document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener(showImage)`

Comment: Pls check whether you linked your javascript file correctly. You can test it by putting a test `alert();`

Comment: @ArchitGargi or check the browser dev tools network tab to make sure the JavaScript is being found/loaded correctly.

Comment: @phuzi I am no expert in browser dev tools so I wrote the method I use

Comment: Where did you include `<script src="external.js"></script>` in your html? Try using `defer` attribute in your `script`, like this: `<script src="external.js" defer></script>`

Comment: @ArchitGargi You don't have to be an expert. Simply opening the browser's development tools usually shows you the browser console. No need to stop learning there, the dev tools are really useful.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I know I just meant I never tried to use them but yes surely I will

Comment: @Molod the <script> is at the bottom of the html doc. I tried the adding the defer but nothing (to my admittedly limited knowledge) happened

Comment: Can you edit the question ands add it there please? To be fair though I was more interested in the HTML for the external version.

Comment: Use the browser developer tools. Look at the Console and see if any errors are reported. Look at the Network tab and find the request for the script. Make sure you get the JS back when the browser requests that URL.

Comment: if defer and placing the script reference at the foot of the document did not work, try adding `load` event on the `window` object and putting all of your external code into it : `window.addEventListener('load', (event) => { // all code here; });` This ensures the script can't run until all images and other resources are loaded.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: @DavePritlove just tried this and still no dice unfortunately

Comment: You still haven't included the external version of your HTML for us to inspect.

Comment: Please remove the solution from the question and add it as an answer. See [answer] for tips on writing a complete and useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved!

```
      const img = "https://storage.googleapis.com/du-prd/books/images/9781538728529.jpg";

      document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", showImage);

      function showImage() {
        document.getElementById("book1").src = img;
      }
```

The reason the above wasn't working was because I did something wrong with the window.addEventListener('load', (event) => { // all code here; }); but after removing that the image appears on a button click